# spectrum of the Hadamard matrices

Tags: matrices, hadamard-matrices

A (±1)-matrix is a matrix whose entries are 1 and −1.
An $n \times n$ (±1)-matrix is called an Hadamard matrix if the rows are
orthogonal.

Equivalently,
An $n \times n$ (±1)-matrix $H$ is Hadamard ⇔ $H H^t = nI_n$,
where $I_n$ denotes the $n \times n$ identity matrix.

In this paper : http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379582902105

A note on the eigenvectors of Hadamard matrices of order $2^n$
R. Yarlagadda
J. Hershey

we have the result that,
If the order of $H$, is $2^n$, then its $2^n$ eigenvalues as follows:

$2^{n - 1}$ eigenvalues are $2^{\frac{n}{2}}$

$2^{n - 1}$ eigenvalues are $- 2^{\frac{n}{2}}$

This result says that $H_n$ has $\frac{n}{2}$ eigen values equal to $n^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and $\frac{n}{2}$ eigenvalues equalt to $- n^{\frac{1}
{2}}$ if **$n = 2^n$**.

My questions are,

1) Is this result true for any Hadamard matrix of order $n$ (this $n$ is any multiple of 4 for which we know there is a Hadamard matrix of that order) ?

2) What is best known result regarding their eigen values?

Thanks for your valuable timing.

Comment: @Sally I am simply interested in Hadamard matrices and tried to explore about them. So I am not sure in which area of Mathematics people do use them. My thought was, this question is self contained. so I thought of having this tag alone. plz help me with this.

Comment: Cross-posted on MO https://mathoverflow.net/questions/233331/spectrum-of-hadamard-matrices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if $H$ is an $n\times n$ Hadamard matrix, then $A:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}H$ is an orthogonal matrix, which implies that if
$$
Av=\lambda v,
$$
then
$$
v^*A^*=\lambda^* v^*,
$$
where the superscript "$*$" denotes Hermitian adjoint, and hence that
$$
v^*v=v^*A^*Av=\lvert\lambda\rvert^2v^*v.
$$
From this it follows that the eigenvalues of $A$ have modulus $1$ and therefore that the eigenvalues of $H$ have modulus $\sqrt{n}$.

It is not the case, however, that the eigenvalues of any Hadamard matrix are $\pm\sqrt{n}$ in equal number.  If you take the matrix $H_n$ of the article you reference, constructed by taking repeated Kronecker products of the matrix
$$
H_1=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & -1
\end{bmatrix},
$$
and, for example, permute some of the rows of the matrix, the resulting matrix may have complex eigenvalues.

The Hadamard matrix
$$
H=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\
1 & -1 & -1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & -1 & -1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix},
$$
for instance, has four distinct eigenvalues of the form $\pm\sqrt{2}\pm\sqrt{2}i$.